# Process database delete action in the same PHP page with post

Tags: php, html, forms, html-post

I'm building PHP application for process employee leave records. In this application the main screen populate database records and action buttons. when user click the action button it take the database id from the table and go through another file to delete that record and then redirect back to the same page. This mechanism implemented using HTML _GET method. that means anyone can see the row ID in the URL feed and if anyone request this url with different row ID, PHP file delete the record since any other security measures not taken place in to prevent that. and also this application not using any kind of session.

this is my href code  for the task I mentioned above.

```
echo "<a href='rejectone.php?id=$lvid' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs m-r-1em'>Cancal</a>";
```

and this is my rejectone.php code

```
<?php
$lid =$_GET['id'];
include 'database.php';
$accval = "Accept";
try {
   $query = "UPDATE leavesrecords SET leavestatus = 'Reject' WHERE lvid = '$lid'";
    $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}

catch(PDOException $exception){
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}   
header( "refresh:0;url=bs.php" );           
?>
```

I have two questions

1.) How can I run the rejectone task inside the same PHP file without redirecting to another PHP file

2.) How can I use HTML _POST method instead of get method to transfer data if I still use jejectone.php file

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change your line:

```
echo "<a href='rejectone.php?id=$lvid' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs m-r-1em'>Cancal</a>";
```

to

```
echo '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs m-r-1em delete-item" primary-key="'.$lvid.'">Cancal</a>';
```

If you haven't included jQuery on your site, you can do it by adding this script to your page, just before closing
`</head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Add this JavaScript file to the bottom of your page, just before closing `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;

        $.post('bs.php', {'id': t.attr('primary-key'), 'delete_item': 1}, function(e){
            window.location = 'bs.php';
        })

    })  
})

</script>
```

Copy your rejectone.php to bs.php, but make these changes:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_item']))
{
    $lid = (int)$_POST['id'];
    include 'database.php';
    $accval = "Accept";
    try {
       $query = "UPDATE leavesrecords SET leavestatus = 'Reject' WHERE lvid = :lid ";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(':lid', $lid );
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    catch(PDOException $exception){
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }

}
```

That is it.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. but somehow this is not working. when I click the button web page display the javascript confirmation but it didn't update the row

Comment: when I run this I get error " ReferenceError: t is not defined "  in console window in firefox

Answer (score -2):

Use ajax post method. See Full example of accepted solution with sample code for more details here : [Delete MySQLi record without showing the id in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459364/delete-mysqli-record-without-showing-the-id-in-the-url/31459470)
Then using jquery remove that record from the page which will give more good UI experience.

Comment: Please provide examples along with your answer. [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: i have updated the comments with the accepted solution URL, so we can avoid duplicates. Does that make sense ?